# Buffer overflow that doesn't overflow

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I am currently learning exploitation from the book Art of Exploitation. The first code in Exploitation part basically taught me a very basic overflow. This is the code from the book:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int value = 5;
    char buffer_one[8], buffer_two[8];
    strcpy(buffer_one, "one"); /* Put "one" into buffer_one. */
    strcpy(buffer_two, "two"); /* Put "two" into buffer_two. */
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[BEFORE] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);
    printf("\n[STRCPY] copying %d bytes into buffer_two\n\n", strlen(argv[1]));
    strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]); /* Copy first argument into buffer_two. */
    printf("[AFTER] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[AFTER] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[AFTER] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);
}
```

After executing with argv[1] = 1234567890 I got

```
[BEFORE] buffer_two is at 0x7ffc97c28ac0 and contains 'two'
[BEFORE] buffer_one is at 0x7ffc97c28ad0 and contains 'one'
[BEFORE] value is at 0x7ffc97c28adc and is 5 (0x00000005)

[STRCPY] copying 9 bytes into buffer_two

[AFTER] buffer_two is at 0x7ffc97c28ac0 and contains '1234567890'
[AFTER] buffer_one is at 0x7ffc97c28ad0 and contains 'one'
[AFTER] value is at 0x7ffc97c28adc and is 5 (0x00000005)
```

[AFTER] buffer_one is supposed to contains "90" instead of "one". I noticed that my offset is 16 bytes instead of 8 bytes (0x7ffc97c28ac0 and 0x7ffc97c28ad0), that's why if doesn't overflow to buffer_one. Any idea what I should look into and is this a very serious issue?

Comment: Does the book instruct you to compile for x64? Does it specify a specific compiler, version, and flags?

Comment: The compiler you use probably lays the data out differently from the compiler used by the author.  You might also note that the program things you copied 9 bytes — you think it should have copied 10 bytes.

Comment: just basic `gcc -o overflow_example overflow_example.c`, I added in `-fno-stack-protector` since without it, it detects stack smashing.

Comment: Why don't you try to see what is the compiler doing by using the `-S` switch and inspecting the assembly?

Comment: Note that the buffers are 16 bytes apart — addresses 0x…C0 and 0x…D0.  You'll need longer strings than 9 or 10 bytes to overflow between them.

Answer (score 1):

> [AFTER] buffer_one is supposed to contains "90" instead of "one".

No, no, a thousand times no. It is *not* supposed to hold *any* particular value. What you are doing is undefined behaviour, the result of which can be *anything,* including it working perfectly.

In fact, if you examine the two addresses, `0x7ffc97c28ac0` and `0x7ffc97c28ad0`, you'll see that they're *sixteen* bytes apart, not eight <sup>(a)</sup>. The implementation is perfectly allowed to do this since its only responsibility is to give you at *least* what you asked for. This means that you'll need a few more bytes in your `strcpy` to overflow the buffer.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> One possible reason for this is because it may be more efficient to align items on 16-byte boundaries for 64-bit architectures (the fact that your addresses are 48 bits rather than 32 seems to indicate this is true). Your book may well have been written with a 32-bit system in mind.

But I stress that's only a *possible* reason. Exploitation requires a very deep understanding of the environment you're working in.

Comment: But, but, but that one book said it should do the thing!

Comment: I think I got what you mean :) it's better for me to think about it that way instead of "the book said it should do the thing". Well thank you all for your help, this noob has a long way to go :D

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't overflow because `buffer_two` is placed in a lower place in memory than `buffer_one`. Because of that, you have to copy `argv[1]` into `buffer_one` so it overflow `buffer_two`.

**buffer_one 0x01 --> buffer_two 0x02** - Overflowing `buffer_two` won't change `buffer_one`.

```c
strcpy(buffer_one, argv[1]); /* Copy first argument into buffer_one. */
```

Memories aren't static, what happens in the book is different than in other machines.